# Which way is the better way of reversing an integer for general purposes?

Tags: java

In most cases, is it better to reverse an integer by extracting digits and putting them onto a string and use valueOf() to obtain the value; or to reverse the integer directly as an integer?

I'm inclined to say the former is better due to it being ubiquitous in the answer solutions of my book whenever they need to reverse an integer.

What is the drawback of using the other approach besides being a bit more time-consuming to write and read?

Comment: How often do you actually need to reverse the decimal digits in an integer?

Comment: other approach is using modulus, `%`

Comment: They both use the modulus operator, unless there are other ways of reversing them?

Comment: Disagree with close votes. This isn't really opinion-based despite the word "better" in the title -- there's a very concrete answer.

Comment: There is no 'general purpose' in reversing an integer whatsoever er. I've never done it in 44 years of computer programming. Asking what the general-purpose solution to it is therefore meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The first way (converting the integer to a string, reversing the string, then converting it back):

- Is easier to understand.
- Is likely to require less code.
- Is likely to be slower.

The second way:

- Is harder to understand.
- Is likely to require more code.
- Is likely to be faster (for one thing, it requires no memory accesses).

Of course, modern computers are so complex that the *only* way to tell whether something is faster is to actually measure it. I said the second way is likely to be faster, but that's just a guess.

**Conclusion:**
If you need the code to be written quickly, do the first one because it's easier.
If you need the code to run quickly, measure how long each one takes to run, and use whichever one is faster.

But, in practice, apart from programming exercises, you will *never* need to reverse an integer. So if you're asking which algorithm is used more often in the real world, the answer is neither.

Comment: Yeah, it took me over 2 hours to get working code by reversing as an integer. Literally facepalmed when I saw a solution that reverses it as a string (or use % to extract right digits and store on a string). Should I continue to practice with these types of problems? The next exercise is to find  "emirps"

Comment: You should continue to practice.  Ditch these types of problems when you find better problems to spend time on.  As pointlessly academic as this seems realizing that built in string methods can solve it for you faster and be easier to understand is actually a very good lesson.

Answer (score 1):

The String method is easier to write and more readable by other programmers (and yourself in 2 weeks). The direct conversion method using modulo is faster and uses less memory but it's a bit harder to read and write.

Note that with JIT compilation and the improvements in JVM in general, the first method could be internally optimized to closely mimic the latter. And we all know that a general rule of programming is to avoid "premature optimization". Thus the more readable method using String is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "better" and what do you mean "for general purpose"?

- For the general purpose of explaining how to code in a textbook, a for loop and modulus is best.
- For the general purpose of being clearly correct, I would suggest converting to string since this is a string operation, not an integer operation.

I haven't seen this operation in production anywhere so I can't attest what anyone actually does with it. I think this was a trick question - your "general purpose" may not exist after all.

Comment: Ah thanks! Kind of depressed that I spent so much time on it... Are these still worth practicing for a beginner?